# Javascript loading a text or json file into array - to be used for form validation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I have a script that validates a form input based on the input being one of the values within an array. If the input value is not within the array, an alert happens, otherwise code continues. I have this working using an array that is populated within the code as below,

```
var arr= ["AANDRUS, Bloemfontein",
         "AANHOU WEN, Stellenbosch",
         "ABBOTSDALE, Western Cape",
         "ABBOTSFORD, East London",
         "ABBOTSFORD, Johannesburg",
         "ABBOTSPOORT, Limpopo",
         "ABERDEEN, Eastern Cape"];
```

but there are +4000 values and the correct way is to create the array in an external file.
I have tried this using `var arr = [<?php require_once("townlist.txt")?>];` and then my validation code looks like this

```
`function quoteValid()                             
{   
    
    var x = document.forms['quoteRequest']['colltown_name'].value;
    if ($.inArray(x, arr) == -1) {
        alert("Please select Collection Town");
        document.forms['quoteRequest']['colltown_name'].focus();
        return false;
    }
return true; 
}`
```

but this does not load the array and the code does not execute as expected.
So, my validation works using the array within the code, but not with the external file loading. I know there are many examples of similar questions on SO, and I have tried replicating quite a few with no positive result.
I have tried using an external json file and text file without it working. I have tried uploading the file to my server (as I am using it on localhost in development) and using the URL to the file on the server. A sample of my text file is as follows

```
[{"AANDRUS, Bloemfontein"},
{"AANHOU WEN, Stellenbosch"},
{"ABBOTSDALE, Western Cape"},
{"ABBOTSFORD, East London"},
{"ABBOTSFORD, Johannesburg"},
{"ABBOTSPOORT, Limpopo"},
{"ABERDEEN, Eastern Cape"}]
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `var arr = [<?php require_once("townlist.txt")?>];` would create an additional array dimension, which you apparently don’t want. So – remove the [ and ]?

Comment: @CBroe - tried that - makes sense - but unfortunately didn't solve the problem.

Comment: So what does the generated HTML code in that place look like? Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled? If not, go and do that first of all.

Comment: You should rather not use `require_once` here, you are not embedding one PHP script into another. Use `file_get_contents` and echo instead.

Comment: @CBroe file_get_contents sorted it out for me - much obliged.